# I need an introduction to MongoDB/NoSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, codeigniter, nosql

I use PHP/mySQL/CodeIgniter pretty heavily, writing sql statements to handle/manipulate data. I feel doing all that is primitive, and I've heard good things about MongoDB, schema-less database.

In MySQL, schemas helps me figure out the structure of the model. Usually, I draw out a class diagram with basic things like: id, title, description, date

What blows my mind is, MongoDB seems insanely simple, it's hard to grasp where to begin. From what I hear/read, it doesn't have a schema. How do I know what type will it return?

How do I build my models, how do I add relations between different "tables"?

What is the standard way to add relations and map out data? I've tried playing with it, but wasn't sure what I was doing was the correct way.

I've tried reading manuals and such, but couldn't find a good article helping me transition from mySQL to MongoDB.

Is there anyway I could see comparisons of Models with *mySQL* and *MongoDB*? Simple things like CRUD.

How do I start, where do I begin?

Comment: Only a partial answer, but try to think of your database only as the place where you store stuff between requests. Your database is not *your application*, your application (code) is your application. The database is only there for *persistence*. This goes well with a proper, complete OOP approach, where your classes/objects represent your models, not where the models represent the database.

Comment: @deceze Makes sense, so basically design the models according to the application, not the database..

Comment: Right, you implement your business logic directly using classes/objects, which embody a certain state and take care that this state only changes according to business logic (`private` properties, setters and all that). The database is just there to persist that state after the script has ended.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend you to try Doctrine or Propel ORM. Propel doesn't have MongoDB support, but you should check them out to avoid doing the completely redundant CRUD code by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart).

> How do I build my models, how do I add relations between different "tables"?

[Answer:](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Philosophy)

> A non-relational approach is the best path to database solutions which scale horizontally to > many machines.

[Answer:](http://How%20do%20I%20know%20what%20type%20will%20it%20return?)

> MongoDB stores data in JSON documents (which we serialize to BSON). JSON provides us a rich data model that seamlessly maps to native programming language types, and since its schema-less, makes it much easier to evolve your data model than with a system with enforced schemas such as a RDBMS.

Check also [What is NoSQL, how does it work, and what benefits does it provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145726/what-is-nosql-how-does-it-work-and-what-benefits-does-it-provide), [I need an advice about NoSQL/MongoDb and data/models structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815731/i-need-an-advice-about-nosql-mongodb-and-data-models-structure) and [Converting simple MySQL database to a NoSQL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201433/converting-simple-mysql-database-to-a-nosql-solution)